# What is the probability there are two or more claims?

Tags: probability, statistics

In a group of policy holders for house insurance,the average number of claims per $100$ policies per year is $\lambda=8.0$. The number of claims for an individual policy holder is assumed to follow a Poisson distribution. 
In a group of $20$ policy holders,what is the probability there are two or more claims?

Comment: Hint: if there are 8 claims per 100 policies, how many are there per 20 policies?  What is the form of the Poisson distribution for that value of $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda=np$ so if n=100 and $\lambda$=8, what is p?

Now take that p to find your new $\lambda$ when n=20. Then let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with that new $\lambda$. Then you can compute:

$P(X\ge2)=1-P(X<2)=1-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$ where $P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$